# How to wrap a non-object data type in an NSValue object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios

How do I convert a non-object objective-c opaque data type (like CGImageRef, CGPDFPageRef) opaque type to an NSValue object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Check out this reference**](http://jongampark.wordpress.com/2008/08/07/nsvalue-and-non-object-types/) about storing arbitrary (non-Object) values into NSValue.

Comment: Please answer a question by quoting article not simply linking to it.